# How to start NSThread after finishing other NSThread?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a couple threads. I want to run them making sure they are executing one after another.
[run thread1];
[run thread2];
When I do this, thread2 is running without waiting thread1 to be finished. I need this because I need value from thread 1, to use on thread 2.

Comment: Sounds like a job for serial dispatch queues.

Comment: What you mean? How I can make thread2 execute, after thread1 is finished?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need threads, for whatever reason, you can do it this way.

```
- (void)startThreadOne
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(executeThreadOne) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void)executeThreadOne
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    // calculate the value
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(threadOneDidFinish) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    [pool release];
}

- (void)threadOneDidFinish
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(executeThreadTwo) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
```

However, this way may be considered old fashioned. Serial dispatch queues should be used when it is possible. [Concurrency Programming Guide.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html)

Comment: Thanks. What I did , is -(void)Thread2Run { while (thread2 isExecuting) { //Do nothing}  Code here }